# I can`t connect my InputField to variable public UnputField in my script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I grab InputField from Unity hierarchy and try to connect it to script var public InputField, it doesn`t work at all.

[image: Picture of unity, menu item image selected]

When I open the list of all available InputFields for the variable, there are none..

Here`s my code:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public GameObject ErrorPanel;

    public InputField InputFieldRoom;

    public void CreateRoom()
    {
        if(InputFieldRoom.text.Length > 3)
        {
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
        roomOptions.MaxPlayers = 10;
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(InputFieldRoom.text, roomOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void JoinRoom()
    {
        if(InputFieldRoom.text.Length > 3) PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(InputFieldRoom.text);
        else ErrorPanel.SetActive(true);
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Racing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the object "InputField" have the `InputField` component attached?

Answer (score 0):

try 'public UnityEngine.UI.InputField InputFieldRoom;'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not opening is because you are using the new textmeshpro so for that you need to change the InputField variable in script to TMP_InputField

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!